# Is there a 'git sed' or equivalent?

Tags: linux, git, bash, sed

Let's say I want to rename a method in source code contained in a git repository. I could do this by hand, but the method name might be in multiple places (e.g., unit test, documentation, actual method). To check where the method is used, I use 'git grep'. I get 'git grep' to show only lines that I want to change, and then I don't have a workflow to automatically change those lines.

I'm looking for an automated way (hopefully using git tools) to do this last step. I was hoping there was some sort of 'git sed' or equivalent, but I can't find any.

The interface I'm thinking would be nice: git sed 's/old-method-name/new-method-name/g'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do a

```
for i in $(git grep --full-name -l old_method_name)
do
 perl -p -i -e 's/old_method_name/new_method_name/g' $i
done
```

stick that in a file somewhere and then alias it as `git sed` in your config.

**Update:** The comment by tchrist below is a much better solution since it prevents perl from spawning repeatedly.

Comment: I suspect you need a `$i` there at the end of the command. Also, you don’t have to launch Perl repeatedly.  It will process all the files you give it as argument.  So `perl -i.orig -pe 's/\bold_method_name\b/new_method_name/g' $(git grep --full-name -l old_method_name)` should suffice.

Comment: Much better. I've fixed the $i in the snippet.

Answer (score 63):

You could use [`git ls-files`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-ls-files.html) in combination with `xargs` and `sed`:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/old-method-name/new-method-name/g'
```

Comment: Awesome! Do I need to worry about whitespace in filenames?

Comment: Yes. If you have whitespace in filenames, use `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 sed ...`.

Comment: Probably but I think you can pass -z to `ls-files` and `-0` to xargs to make it work.

Comment: This technique kept failing for me, b/c I have submodules in the repo that cause sed to exit before getting to all of the files listed in ls-files. At least I think that's what's going on. I'm still troubleshooting it, as I favor this approach over @NoufalIbrahim, because the method-name is only in one place.

Comment: Note that you need GNU sed for this (e.g. it won’t work on macOS with its default `sed`, because of how its `-i` option works).

Comment: `git ls-files` will include submodules which are not files. Instead of `git ls-files` use:

`git ls-files | grep -Fxvf  <(grep "^\s*\[submodule " .gitmodules | cut -d '"' -f2)`

Comment: @kirelagin specifying `''` as extension will solve that problem.

Answer (score 25):

Thanks to both Noufal and Greg for their posts. I combined their solutions, and found one that uses git grep (more robust than git ls-files for my repo, as it seems to list only the files that have actual src code in them - not submodule folders for example), and also has the old method name and new method name in only one place:

In the `[alias]` block of my `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
sed = ! git grep -z --full-name -l '.' | xargs -0 sed -i -e
```

To use:

```
git sed 's/old-method-name/new-method-name/ig'
```

Comment: This works in Linux, but on OS X it copies all the files in the repository and adds `-e` to the end of them. This seems to work better: `git grep -z --full-name -l '.' | xargs -0 sed -i ''`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution that combines those of of Noufal and claytontstanley and avoids touching files that won't change.

In the `[alias]` block of my `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
psed = !sh -c 'git grep --null --full-name --name-only --perl-regexp -e \"$1\" | xargs -0 perl -i -p -e \"s/$1/$2/g\"' -
```

To use:

```
git psed old_method_name new_method_name
```

Comment: can I also use this for general substitutions, e.g. substitutions that include spaces?

Comment: Yes, but depending on your shell you may have to adjust how many times you quote the arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there's. In Ubuntu the package [`git-extras`](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/man/git-sed.md) provides the command. Install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-extras
```

Use it like bellow e.g. to correct a spelling issue quickly:

```
$ git sed 'qoute' 'quote'
```

Unfortunately it doesn't support file filters like what git grep does:

```
$ git grep -e 'class' -- '*.py'
```

The same functionality also exists on Mac and other operating systems. Checkout its [installation page](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Installation.md).

Comment: Capture groups (https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) work with `git sed` as well: `git sed "\(\w*\)" "Here's a word: \1"`

Answer (score 3):

Unhappy with most other solutions provided (which is basically just a string-replace on git tracked files) I wrote my own script: [git-sed](https://github.com/ext/git-sed).

- It supports any expression sed supports (e.g `git sed '1{/^$/d}'`)
- Can run on a subset of paths in the repo (`git sed 's/foo/bar' src tests`)
- Multiple expressions (`git sed -e 's/foo/bar' -e '/bar/d'`).
- etc...

Just drop it anywhere in `PATH` to use it or add an alias pointing to the full path.

Answer (score 1):

Note that starting [git 2.1 (Q3 2014)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/75cc6c67e25656c1b19c7c8f6ca29d1463aefef4/Documentation/RelNotes/2.1.0.txt#L52-L54), you can set "`full-name`" by default for [`git grep`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep).
(See [commit 6453f7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6453f7b34864c1a639cc367f576476ee3be1456f) by [Andreas Schwab](https://github.com/andreas-schwab))

> "`git grep`" learned `grep.fullname` configuration variable to force "`--full-name`" to be default.
>   This may cause regressions on scripted users that do not expect this new behaviour.

That means the previous solutions can benefit from:

```
git config grep.full-name true
```

And use:

```
psed = !sh -c 'git grep --null --name-only --perl-regexp -e \"$1\" | xargs -0 perl -i -p -e \"s/$1/$2/g\"' -
```

Answer (score 0):

See [git-search-replace](https://github.com/da-x/git-search-replace) on github - it's designed for this exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a git sed which supports file filtering:

```
#!/bin/bash

split=$(($# + 1))

for i in $(seq 1 $#); do
   if [[ "${!i}" = "--" ]]; then
       split=$i
   fi
done

git ls-files -z "${@:$split:$#}" | xargs -0 sed -b -i "${@:1:$(($split - 1))}"
```

(You probably don't want the `-b` parameter on non-Windows platforms; it's necessary on Windows to preserve Windows-style newlines.)

You can then add an alias in your `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    sed = ! <path to git-sed>
```

so that you can use it like `git sed -e <your expression> -- <path filter>`.